# Can't position a div above other docs?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to position a div above others through absolute positioning. But the div is still under an AdSense ad. My website is located at http://tinyurl.com/q3uwbf3. Try out the div by clicking on login on top-right corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue has to do with [Z-INDEX.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Make sure you set it higher than the element that is hiding your DIV. Think of Z-INDEX as possible layers on top of each other.

```
#loginmenu {
z-index:999;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase/Add the **`z-index`** property, will fix the issue.  On inspecting using developer tools I fixed it

```
#loginmenu {
z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with the z-index, which basically determines what's in front and what's in the back.

Take a look at this: http://www.echoecho.com/csslayers.htm

Answer (score 0):

**give z-index 1; in the style tagg or css**

```
#loginmenu {
z-index: 1;
}

 <div style="display: block; z-index: 1;" id="loginmenu">

</div>
```

## Any element with higher z index comes upper